# schema importer Extension class in .net webservice

Tags: .net, web-services

What is scchema importer Extension class in .net webservice.Recently i came across this class in one of the support project.

In that project its not using now.

So i am curious to find the practical implementation of this calss.I have gone through few artcles but not clear about the concept.

Is this avilable in WCF services also.If not what is the replacement for this.

plese give your suggestions?

If someone already used it please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these extensions you can avoid that proxy classes are generated, but known types from local assemblies can be used.

For example you can use it when your client and webservice both use the same shared assembly (like your company's framework) and the webservice returns a certain type from this assembly.